# How to diagnose which driver or program cause stuttering in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, lag

My Windows 10 system experiencing regular lags and stuttering, approximately once per minute. This is especially noticeable when I'm watching video. Strangely, this problem disappears when GPU-heavy game is running. I've found that uninstalling all "Intel Dynamic Tuning" devices from Device Manager significantly reduces the lags, but they still occur. I have another Windows 10 installation on this PC, and there are no such lags in another Windows. Maybe, there is some buggy driver or autorun program causes this. Windows and drivers for both Intel and Nvidia GPUs are updated to the latest versions.

Are there diagnostic tools that help to find out what program or driver cause this? Or is there is a solution to this problem that I overlooked?

Update: Process Explorer and Autoruns from Sysinternals Suite were helpful. I disabled everything that looked suspicious with Autoruns and also disabled "SysMain" in services.msc applet. Lags were reduced, but didn't disappear completely (however, I don't know what exactly helped). Process Explorer shows that when lags occur, CPU usage of "System" increases from 1% to 20%; of "Interrupts" to 10%, and GPU usage of video player increases from 10% to 30%.

Comment: One approach would be to run Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor for 15 minutes or so and see what process is using a lot of CPU and also what process is using a lot of disk. Both measurements are available in the tool.

Comment: What type of Intel Network Adapter do you have?

Comment: I would not use the "Windows Update" drivers for your Intel and NVIDIA devices. Download the latest drivers from the manufacturers website and install those instead. Be sure for the NVIDIA driver to select "Custom" when installing and tick the box that says "Perform Clean Installation". This will remove all traces of the previous driver before installing the new one.

Comment: Intel and NVIDIA drivers are from the official websites. Network adapter is WiFi 6 AX200, VEN_8086&DEV_2723. Strangely, Resource Monitor doesn't show high CPU load when lags occur. Probably, it's something low level, linked with drivers, because mouse cursor and keyboard lag too when this occurs.

Comment: It would help to know computer model and what codecs are used by the videos that cause lagging.

Comment: it could be *low or medium* utilization that is causing the issues: consider if the load is right at the threshold of handoff from intel integrated gpu to the nvidia gpu then you might get latency as they switch, and then if it drops, it switches again, repeat. More info about the system might be helpful

Comment: This is Tuxedo XP17 laptop, Intel UHD Graphics VEN_8086&DEV_9BC4 and NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU VEN_10DE&DEV_249C. In NVIDIA Control Panel I set to always use high-speed processor. About the codecs: my test file is webm file downloaded from Youtube with youtube-dl; and I've installed the latest K-Lite codec pack.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've solved the problem with stuttering. I uninstalled all video drivers with [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-v18053-released) and then installed the latest Intel and Nvidia drivers again. Unfortunately, I hadn't found any utility that can help to find what driver exactly caused stuttering; probably, it still doesn't exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Right click your network adapter and click "Configure"

[image: 1]

Now under the "Advanced" tab make sure both Transmit Buffers and Receive Buffers are set to 1024. This is an optimal setting for video playback.

[image]

Select Speed and Duplex and make sure it is set to "Auto Negotiation". This will ask for the best speed your broadband router is able to offer.

[image]

Now right click your ethernet adapter > Status

Make sure it says 1.0Gbps for speed. If lower than this you might need to check your cables are Cat5e or above in order to achieve 1Gbps. Your network adapter also needs to be capable of such speed, so check the model number online.

[image]

Reboot your computer and let me know if this helps. I can modify the answer with further optimisation tips if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, but lags are most probably not linked with my Internet connection: they occur when playing local video files in Media Player Classic too. And sometimes they are visible in desktop interactions, as delayed reactions on mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Do you happen to have your two windows installations on different drives? I wonder if your problem OS is having I/O issues on the drive it's reading and writing from. For example. if your good OS is running from SSD and your bad OS is running on an older HDD.

Comment: No, there are both on fast SSDs, and lags happen when disk access LED on laptop is not actively blinking. The difference is, the OS with problem was moved from old laptop by copying the partition, so I'm searching for remaining old drivers that can cause issues. Are there analogs in Windows for dmesg on Linux or logcat in Android?

Comment: I wouldn't have copied a partition from an old device onto a new device. The best method would have been to backup all your important data and copy it back over after doing a fresh windows installation on the new device's SSD. I'm betting if you do this the problem will go away. I know it's not giving you a solve, but to me this is the cleanest way to get rid of this problem.